# Running a Web Browers within a html page

Tags: html, http, browser, web

Hi there I am wondering if someone might help me with this.  I have this http server that I run that has my music and bookmarks and such saved on it.  I would like to implement a feature where there would be a window below the buttons at the top of the page that would act as a mini web browser within the page.  Something that would open to google and then I could search just like a browser run on a computer but like what I could load anywhere.  I doubt i'm an advanced enough coder to do this.  I just want to know if its possible.

Thanks Carl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to embed Google's "Custom Search Engine" in an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Keep in mind that websites can prevent you from embedding their content on your site (using [X-frame-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)), so it may not work for all websites.

Give it a try:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/custom" width="100%" height="200px"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E6R4h/

---

### Edit:

You appear to be using Google's "Custom Search Engine" API. But you are using the method that only displays a search box. There are several layout methods from which to choose:

> 1. **standard**: A search box and search results, displayed in the same `<div>`.
> 2. **two-column**: A two-column layout with search results on one side and a search box on the other. If you plan to insert multiple
>      elements in two-column mode in your webpage, you can use the gname
>      attribute to pair a search box with a block of search results.
> 3. **searchbox-only**: A standalone search box.
> 4. **searchresults-only**: A standalone block of search results.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#overview

Here are examples for using the ["standard"](http://jsfiddle.net/PvUFu/1/) or ["two-column"](http://jsfiddle.net/PvUFu/) method.

Comment: Ok thanks I've been trying to use i frames and their not actually showing up as a page. its just blank white page in a box. Its being frustrating.

Comment: Yes, check the HTTP response header for [X-frame-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). If it says "SAMEORIGIN", embedding is prohibited.

Comment: Where whould I check I've been looking for quite a while and I can't seem to find where its located

Comment: ok yes its set to sameorigin how do i change that

Comment: You can't change response headers. "SAMEORGIN" means you cannot embed that URL in an iframe. However, since the "Custom Search Engine" URL responds with "ALLOWALL", you can embed that URL.

Comment: what should I do so the results show on my web page below the search bar instead of in a new page                                    <script> (function() { var cx = '017448033450929209334:9ektco2iryc'; var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true; gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s); })(); </script> <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>

Comment: I have updated my answer with API methods.